# How to select records where all of their statuses are zero?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

Suppose I have following tables
`Person table` and `personStatus table`.

```
declare @Persons table
(PersonId int)

insert into @Persons select 10   
insert into @Persons select 11    

declare @PersonStatus table
(id int,statuss int)

insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(10,0)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(10,0)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(11,1)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(10,0)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(11,0)
```

Now I want to find person IDs that **all** of their statuses are zero
result is just ---> 10

How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to return a person who has no rows in the child table?

Comment: No this is not my scenario

Comment: do you want to return only person whose all status is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  id
FROM    @PersonStatus
GROUP   BY ID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT statuss) = 1 AND
        MAX(statuss) = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6804/2)

OR

```
SELECT  id
FROM    @PersonStatus
GROUP   BY ID
HAVING  MAX(statuss) = MIN(statuss) AND
        MAX(statuss) = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6804/3)

Answer (score 1):

Since I assume the `@Persons` table has more than just a `PersonId` column and you might want other columns from there, I think `@Persons` needs to be part of the query.

```
SELECT p.PersonId --, other columns from p
 FROM @Persons AS p
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM @PersonStatus
   WHERE id = p.PersonId
   GROUP BY id HAVING MAX(statuss) = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct p.id from @PersonStatus as p
where Statuss = 0
and not exists (select null from @Personstatus as t
                where p.id = t.id and t.statuss <> 0)
```